# codeigniter-restserver how to put json into the response

Tags: json, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver

I'm trying to put json data into the codeigniter-restserver response, but the json code is put into double quotes effectively rendering it unreadable.
I'm trying to set the response like this currently:

```
$this->response(array(
    'status' => $result['success'],
    'error' => $result['cause'],
    'result' => $result['result']
), $result['statuscode']);
```

Where `$result['result']` is the json code.

Comment: [This is the CI documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html#CI_Output::set_content_type). And [here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/olivierobert/4130171) of how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the  `json_decode()` to convert your json data in to array. Try it...

```
$this->response(array(
'status' => $result['success'],
'error' => $result['cause'],
'result' => json_decode($result['result'],true)
), $result['statuscode']);
```